# how do I cut and stack brush for chipping?

Tags: tree-removal

I am cutting a lot of brush (stalks 1-2" diameter, never larger than 3")). And a few young trees up to 5" which  I am denuding and disposing of the logs separately, so what remains is branches.

I want to have someone take the brush away, and I gather they would chip it first.

How do I cut it for easy chipping?

How do I stack it?

Comment: I gotta go find this site for you.  Forget doing stacking.  There are people who have purchased an honest to goodness clean up any and all debris, fill a pup truck full of chips, take it all away with absolutely no effort on your part.  Similar to a lumber mill on wheels.  I'll go look for those videos...

Comment: Here is an idea: So many of these companies with all sizes and styles of chippers, loaders and to do it yourself I doubt you'll save moola. https://video.search.yahoo.com/search/video?fr=mcafee&p=mobile+chipper+debris+removal#id=45&vid=8593493b3d2432171285e72db46e581d&action=view

Comment: The cut location is not truck-accessible. Blazing a road in there is not possible.  Getting the cuttings out 1000' to a truck-accessible location is 90% of the total work and I'd go broke paying anyone labor for that. I have no interest in chipping myself, those machines are too dangerous and I want the chips gone too.

Comment: Look up Wranglerstar on YouTube.  They do not need a 'road' usually to get to the site.  These machines are too dangerous for YOU to handle but these are professionals and these machines are breath takingly efficient, smart.  Costs NOTHING to get an estimate and that is also a good time to learn all about chipping...they will LOVE to take your chips they are like gold!  Remember TANKS?  Tractors are tanks...and the new ones will blow you away for accessibility.  Power.  Flexibility...great self employment type job...very affordable, check it out costs nothing.  Why do you want chips moved?

Comment: None of those machines could access the site. I don't want to chip on site because it's right on a dammed river and HUGE quantities of those chips will end up behind the dam, visible from a main road... Everytime it rains... For years... They'll know it's us.

Comment: I guess I am having a tough time envisioning your project. True, rivers are a big deal with any construction.  Most rivers have buffer zones depending on the type of river and habitat.  Salmon rivers, streams have huge buffer zones...300 feet to 600 feet from the high water mark of the 'creek' or river on one side is off limits to EVERYTHING.  Same on the other side.  Why, though, the chips would end up in the river I am not understanding.  They decompose, stay in place unless on a slope with lots of water sheeting over the surface...They decompose quickly, within a year with a bit of help.

Comment: Can you burn those branches if there are problems with getting machinery/vehicles to your location?

Comment: I would NEVER ever promote breaking the riparian laws.  They are a few of the best laws made.  And I really would love to see a site that is un accessible by big machines.  Look up Wrangle Star.  He has some amazing videos of mobile chipper rigs as well as mobile lumber yards.  Maybe a few pictures?  More information?

Comment: Now there is a great duh howdy plan...burning.  Is that doable?  Got get going before the burning bans go into place (May?)...gosh, how much debris DO you have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have two chippers (one petrol, one electrical both with max. diameter of 5 cm) but unfortunately both are too small for chipping larger branches not to mention trunks.

This spring I've decided to remove about 50 apple trees and since I didn't want just to trow whole trees away I did this:

- removed limbs/branches and moved logs away
- cut larger branches into smaller parts (trying to have them as strait as possible)
- stacked branches in few piles so that thicker part of branches are aligned in same direction (towards the chipper) for easier feeding into machine (like in my superb drawing :D )

  ```
       \ | / 
        \|/
         |    <- (piles of branches)
         |

         V
         V 
     [chipper]
  ```

Most chippers have some kind of funnel shaped opening/feeder so you can't really put branches in reverse position. Once the chipper grabs one end of branch and starts grinding, it will continue to pull in the rest of it.

If chipper is manually loaded, having branches aligned in same direction will shorten amount of time (and stress if branches are tangled).

Anyway, IMO it all depends on size and type of chipper. With really big machine it doesn't really matter what goes in and in what direction.

https://youtu.be/S39TPZ_5iLU